# Confirmação visual de carregamento de páginas em PWA

Tags: php, wordpress, pwa

criei um PWA de um site feito em Wordpress, ficou bom, parecendo um app.
Mas estou com um problema, quando clico em algum link/imagem que me leve a outra pagina o site demora para responder. Nesse tempo não tenho nenhuma confirmação visual de que estou "indo pra outro lugar". Quando estou usando o chrome no celular aparece um barra de progresso abaixo da barra de endereços. Mas no PWA a barra de endereços não aparece. Coloquei um plugin de page loader, mas ele só é ativado no carregamento da próxima página, ou seja, não é ativado logo que eu clico para ir. Gostaria de uma forma de que, quando o usuário clicar em qualquer link esse page loader seja exibido o que até mesmo a tela fique branca, alguma coisa assim. Para dar a sensação de que a pagina já esta sendo carregada logo que a pessoa clicou.
URL do meu site: www.kifome.app

Comment: Sua pergunta tem poucas informações. Que plugin é esse? Coloque trechos do seu código.

Comment: O plugin é um page loader simples. Gostaria que quando clicasse em qualquer link tivesse alguma coisa confirmação de que a página está carregando. Mas me disseram que minha página está muito lenta. Não sei exatamente como melhorar isso no WordPress.